# why am i getting this error in compiling programme?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mingw-w64

i am trying to compile c file in **linux** OS but i'm getting so many errors.
I searched it on internet and found solution that is to install mingw-w64. I installed but getting the same error.

here is my first.c file :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 printf("Hello world");
 return 0;
}
```

here what i got after compiling :

```
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/dj/Desktop/c/graphics]
└─# gcc first.c -o output                                                                                                                                            1 ⚙
In file included from /usr/local/include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/corecrt_stdio_config.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/stdio.h:9,
                 from first.c:1:
/usr/local/include/_mingw.h:272:2: error: #error Only Win32 target is supported!
  272 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/corecrt_stdio_config.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/stdio.h:9,
                 from first.c:1:
/usr/local/include/_mingw.h:580:14: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__debugbreak’
  580 | void __cdecl __debugbreak(void);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/_mingw.h:581:36: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__debugbreak’
  581 | __MINGW_INTRIN_INLINE void __cdecl __debugbreak(void)
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from first.c:1:
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:93:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__acrt_iob_func’
   93 | _CRTIMP FILE *__cdecl __acrt_iob_func(unsigned index);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:158:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__mingw_sscanf’
  158 |   int __cdecl __mingw_sscanf(const char * __restrict__ _Src,const char * __restrict__ _Format,...);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:161:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__mingw_vsscanf’
  161 |   int __cdecl __mingw_vsscanf (const char * __restrict__ _Str,const char * __restrict__ Format,va_list argp);

...
/usr/local/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h:857:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_vscwprintf_l’
  857 |   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _vscwprintf_l(const wchar_t *_Format,_locale_t _Locale,va_list _ArgList);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h:858:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_fwscanf_l’
  858 |   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _fwscanf_l(FILE *_File,const wchar_t *_Format,_locale_t _Locale,...);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h:859:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_swscanf_l’
  859 |   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _swscanf_l(const wchar_t *_Src,const wchar_t *_Format,_locale_t _Locale,...);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h:860:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_snwscanf_l’
  860 |   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _snwscanf_l(const wchar_t *_Src,size_t _MaxCount,const wchar_t *_Format,_locale_t _Locale,...);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h:861:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘_wscanf_l’
  861 |   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _wscanf_l(const wchar_t *_Format,_locale_t _Locale,...);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
first.c:4:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
    4 | {
      | ^
first.c:7: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
    7 | }
      |
```

please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You definitely do not need Mingw on Linux. Get rid of it

Comment: try `gcc -o output first.c` then run it with `./output`. Notice the `#error` right at the top of your output.

Comment: again i got the same error                                                                                                  `In file included from /usr/local/include/corecrt.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/crtdefs.h:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/conio.h:9,
                 from first.c:1:
/usr/local/include/_mingw.h:272:2: error: #error Only Win32 target is supported!
  272 | #error Only Win32 target is supported!`

Answer (score 3):

The Mingw-w64 compiler is for windows. If you're using linux, then you just need to install `gcc` which should be already preinstalled on your system. Just remove the mingw package and it should work then.